# Event Scheduler in PostgreSQL?

Tags: events, postgresql, schedule

Is there a similar event scheduler from MySQL available in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While a lot of people just use cron, the closest thing to a built-in scheduler is PgAgent.  It's a component to the pgAdmin GUI management tool.  A good intro to it can be found at [Setting up PgAgent and doing scheduled backups](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/19-Setting-up-PgAgent-and-Doing-Scheduled-Backups.html).

Answer (score 6):

> [pg_cron](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron) is a simple, cron-based job scheduler for PostgreSQL that runs
>   inside the database as an extension. A background worker initiates
>   commands according to their schedule by connecting to the local
>   database as the user that scheduled the job.
>
> pg_cron can run multiple jobs in parallel, but it runs at most one
>   instance of a job at a time. If a second run is supposed to start
>   before the first one finishes, then the second run is queued and
>   started as soon as the first run completes. This ensures that jobs run
>   exactly as many times as scheduled and don’t run concurrently with
>   themselves.
>
> If you set up pg_cron on a hot standby, then it will start running the
>   cron jobs, which are stored in a table and thus replicated to the hot
>   standby, as soon as the server is promoted. This means your periodic
>   jobs automatically fail over with your PostgreSQL server.

Source: [citusdata.com](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/09/09/pgcron-run-periodic-jobs-in-postgres/)

Comment: installation is a little complicated.
Can it be install in Aurora ?