# Execute procedure automatically

Tags: postgresql

I have this table

```
create table preñadas(
    hierro varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    hierro_toro varchar (30) NOT NULL,
    fecha_esperada_parto timestamp,
    observaciones varchar(200),
    primary key (hierro),
    foreign key (hierro) references animales,
    foreign key (hierro_toro) references animales (hierro)
);
```

i would like to eliminate a record automatically from it when `now()` is one month past `fecha_esperada_parto`

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: A cron job that runs a `DELETE` statement. https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/43937/188406

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event Scheduler in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839469/event-scheduler-in-postgresql)